# Добавить задачу для cron на выполнение раз в минуту при запуске инсталлятора

Tags: bash, cron, crontab

Нужно создать инсталлятор для набора сервисов или для каждого сервиса в отдельности. Если сервис падает, его нужно перезапустить, и для этого написан sh-скрипт, который ищет живой процесс и запускает сервис, если такой процесс не найдет. Этот скрипт запускается раз в минуту по крону. Инсталлятор должен не только разместить файлы сервисов и bash-скрипты, но кроме этого должен настроить крон для запуска sh-скриптов раз в минуту.

Как можно настроить крон из инсталлятора? Есть какая-либо системная команда для простого добавления задания или здесь не обойтись без редактирования конфига crontab? Если нужно изменять конфиг крона, как можно сделать это из инсталлятора?

Comment: Почему бы не воспользоваться стандартными средствами операционной системы по управлению сервисами? systemd и всё такое

Comment: какая ОС, какая система иницализации, на чем "сервисы"? .В `systemd` уже все за вас сделали, гляньте документацию.

Answer (score 1):

В раздел [Service] Вашего файла `<some>.service` пропишите директиву `Restart=` и подберите для него одно из подходящих Вам значений из списка

> Takes one of no, on-success, on-failure, on-abnormal, on-watchdog, on-abort, or always.

[Для справки](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

Answer (score 0):

`cp your-cron-snippet /etc/cron.d/`
или поместить его туда средствами вашего менеджера пакетов.